# How can I optimise this css code for not writing same css code several times in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input box. Where the values are already defined in or it will be generated in some other rules that's why they all have **individual** **id's**.

html code:

```
<input class="box" type="text" style="width:8%; text-align:center" id="a" value="A" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" style="width:8%; text-align:center" id="b" value="B" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" style="width:8%; text-align:center" id="c" value="C" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" style="width:8%; text-align:center" id="d" value="D" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" style="width:8%; text-align:center" id="e" value="E" readonly="true"/>
```

now suppose, i've to decrease the size of the **width** 8 to 6. Then I've to write `width:6%'` 5 times, which is redundant thus I don't wanna use it. Is there any way I can improve this or write any loop for this?

Comment: Can you use css or js ?

Comment: For cases like this (where you have styles for multiple elements), it's best to use an external stylesheet or a <style> tag; then you can use a CSS selector like `.box {}` or `#a, #b, #c, #d, #e {}` to apply styles to all of your inputs

Comment: Why can't you use [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)?

Comment: `.box { width: 6%; text-align:center; }` instead of inline styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML elements already have a CSS class attribute, so you can style them like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 6%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input class="box" type="text" id="a" value="A" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" id="b" value="B" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" id="c" value="C" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" id="d" value="D" readonly="true"/>
<input class="box" type="text" id="e" value="E" readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CSS classes is exactly to handle this situation. Rather than put  `style="width:8%; text-align:center"` in each tag, you could use your box class to change all of them at once.

```
INPUT.box {
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The trick, of course, is to use the right CSS selector to access the things you want to change as a group.  `INPUT.box` means "all INPUT elements with the class box"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Property values don't work that way - you're supposed to specify the values without quotes.

Comment: Good Lord, it really IS Monday.  Thanks, fixing my answer. Much appreciated.